# Completely remove custom post type permalinks ("One Page" website)

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, search-engines

I created a one page style website that I converted to WordPress. The website include a blog, but I'm not using the usual WordPress way to display the post as I'm using a modal window appearing on click to displaying it. So basically I'm not using the Pages/Posts/Comments admin sections at all. Instead I decided to go with custom post types and create my own PHP loops. This is working pretty great for now.

But I have a problem with permalinks. Everytime I want to create a CPT, there's a permalink attributed to the "post".
For example here's my CPT settings for a "carousel logo display" section (I use CPT UI plugin to create my CPTs, saying it just in case) :

```
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => false,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => false,
    "exclude_from_search" => true,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => false,
    "query_var" => false,
```

Which is working in a way. I mean that I don't have that `mywebsite.com/CPT_Name/blablabla/` type of links anymore. But I still have something like `mywebsite.com/?post_type=CPT_Name&p=43` working instead (displaying my homepage), which is scary in a way.
I don't care if anyone goes on these links, because there is 0,1% of chance it happens (as of course I'll not publish/use these links at all). But I'm scared that Search engines get these permalinks in their database.

So basically, am I doing CPT the good way ? Do permalinks like the one I talked just before risks to appear on search engines ? Do I need to redirect these permalinks to my 404 page ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to set `publicly_queryable` to `false`, which should prevent those ugly permalinks from being generated / working.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This was indeed the last option I needed to disable to finally block all the CPTs permalinks.